# Calling a function without callback inside a Async module

Tags: javascript, fs, async.js

i have a problem with this example in the [Async documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map):

```
async.map(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.stat, function(err, results) {
   // results is now an array of stats for each file
});
```

this example calls `fs.stat` to use in every element of the array with `(item,callback)` but i don't know what callback use, where is the callback define?

Comment: The callback function is supplied by the async library. You could equally have written `function(item, callback) { fs.stat(item, callback); }`

Comment: The link you provided also documents the `iteratee` which is an [`AsyncFunction`](https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html#AsyncFunction) and the `callback` argument which is defined as `(err, results)`.

Comment: @Bergi i assume that something like this happens but i don't find anything in the documentation

Comment: @FernandoLlallire The docs you linked say "*The `iteratee` is applied to each item in `coll` and invoked with `(item, callback)`.*" The `callback` argument is created by the library, defined somewhere in its intestines. Does it matter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You *could* use node's built-in `util.promisify` and skip the need for `async.map` and *async.js* altogether -

```
const { promisify } = require('util')

const fs = require('fs')

const files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

Promise.all(files.map(promisify(fs.stat)))
  .then(results => /* results is now an array of stats for each file */)
  .catch(err => /* err is the first error to occur */)
```

Promises are the new concurrency primitive in modern JavaScript environments. They can be easily used in *all* scenarios where a node-style error-first callback is expected, in the format of `(err, res) => { ... }`. This is the case for `async.map`.

Promises mitigate against a slew of problems that arise from the infamous "callback hell". If, for whatever reason you cannot use Promises and must use node-style callbacks, maybe this well help your understanding. I learn best by seeing complete working examples, so in less than 50 lines we implement `asyncMap` and an example async function for you to see how each piece plays its role -

```js
const delayedDouble = (x, callback) =>
  setTimeout        // delay a function
    ( () =>         // the function to delay 
        callback    // call the callback
          ( null    // with no error
          , x * 2   // and the result
          )
    , 1000          // delay the function 1000 milliseconds
    )

const asyncMap = (arr, func, cb) =>
{ const loop = (res, i) =>  // make a named loop
    i >= arr.length         // if i is out of bounds
      ? cb(null, res)       // send no error and the final result
      : func                // otherwise call the user-supplied func
          ( arr[i]          // with the current element 
          , (err, x) =>     // and a callback
              err                     // if there is an error
                ? cb(err, null)       // send error right away, with no result
                : loop                // otherwise keep looping
                    ( [ ...res, x ]   // with the updated result
                    , i + 1           // and the updated index
                    )
          )
  return loop // initialize the loop
     ( []     // with the empty result
     , 0      // and the starting index
     ) 
}
  
asyncMap             // demo of asyncMap
  ( [ 1, 2, 3 ]      // example data
  , delayedDouble    // async function with (err,res) callback
  , (err, res) =>    // final callback for asyncMap
      err            // if an error occured ...
        ? console.error('error', err)  // display error
        : console.log('result', res)   // otherwise display result
  )
  
console.log('please wait 3 seconds...')
// please wait 3 seconds...
// <3 second later>
// result [ 2, 4, 6 ]
```

Above, `delayedDouble` *always* succeeded by calling `callback(null, x * 2)`. If we had a function that sometimes failed, we could see that `asyncMap` properly passes the error along

```
const tenDividedBy = (x, callback) =>
  setTimeout
    ( () =>
        x === 0
          // when x is zero, send an error and no result
          ? callback(Error('cannot divide 10 by zero'), null)
          // otherwise, send no error and the result
          : callback(null, 10 / x)
    , 1000
    )

asyncMap
  ( [ 1, 0, 6 ]   // data contains a zero!
  , tenDividedBy
  , (err, res) =>
      err
        ? console.error('error', err)
        : console.log('result', res)
  )
  // error Error: cannot divide 10 by zero
```

If there is no error, the result comes through as expected -

```
asyncMap
  ( [ 1, 2, 3, ]
  , tenDividedBy
  , (err, res) =>
      err
        ? console.error('error', err)
        : console.log('result', res)
  )
  // result [ 10, 5, 3.3333333333333335 ]
```

We can make our case for using Promises by seeing the same program written using Promises instead of callbacks. As you can see below, Promises allow the code to remain much flatter. Also note how `asyncMap` doesn't need to concern itself with the error branch of the code; errors are automatically bubbled up and can caught using `.catch` at any point in the async computation -

```js
const asyncMap = (arr, func) =>
{ const loop = (res, i) =>
    i >= arr.length
      ? Promise.resolve(res)
      : func(arr[i]).then(x => loop([...res, x], i + 1))
  return loop ([], 0)
}

const tenDividedBy = x =>
  x === 0
    ? Promise.reject(Error('cannot divide 10 by zero'))
    : Promise.resolve(10 / x)

asyncMap([1, 2, 0], tenDividedBy)
  .then(res => console.log('result', res))
  .catch(err => console.error('error', err))
// Error: cannot divide 10 by zero

asyncMap([1, 2, 3], tenDividedBy)
  .then(res => console.log('result', res))
  .catch(err => console.error('error', err))
// result [ 10, 5, 3.3333 ]
```

This is a nice exercise and all, but the first part of this answer suggests to use `Promise.all`. `Promise.all` exists so that we don't have to write things like `asyncMap` by hand. As an added benefit, `Promise.all` processes the computations in parallel, instead of serially.

Comment: that _could_ is leaning toward a _should_

Comment: While I agree that this is how one should write such code today, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user633183 that is a excellent response but my question is about the definition of a callback in the map function. i always should use promise instead of a callback. but when i saw the example i can't find where is the callback defined

Comment: In the complete example, `asyncMap` provides the callback for `func`; you can see this as `(err, x) => ...` in the code snippet. The final callback `cb` supplied by the user at the call site. Does that answer your question?